# problem in getting the specific list

Tags: java, binary-search

I have written a class which at first you pass a list to its constructor and then it will find all its permutations and then I make a BST with each of them and I will find their average access time.all these works are OK! BUT I want to keep the permutation which has the least average access time and I will get the least average access time but it won't give me the specific permutation of that least average access time.

for example I have these permutations  with their average access time:

```
[digit :3  probability: 0.2 level:1, digit :1  probability: 0.3 level:2, digit :2  probability: 0.1 level:3, digit :6  probability: 0.1 level:2, digit :5  probability: 0.1 level:3]
1.6
[digit :3  probability: 0.2 level:1, digit :1  probability: 0.3 level:2, digit :2  probability: 0.1 level:3, digit :5  probability: 0.1 level:2, digit :6  probability: 0.1 level:3]
1.6

[digit :1  probability: 0.3 level:1, digit :2  probability: 0.1 level:2, digit :3  probability: 0.2 level:3, digit :5  probability: 0.1 level:4, digit :6  probability: 0.1 level:5]
2.0
```

I want to get one of the fist permutations but it will print the last permutation !

CODE:

```
    public void getAverageAccessTime(ArrayList<Element> result) {
    averageAccessTime = 0.0;
    averageAccessTime += result.get(0).getProbability();
    result.get(0).setLevel(1);
    root = new DNode(result.get(0), null, null);
    for (int i = 1; i < result.size(); i++) {
        insert(result.get(i));
    }
    if(minAverageAccessTime==0){
        minAverageAccessTime = averageAccessTime;
        listWithMinimumAverageAccessTime = result;

    }
    else if(minAverageAccessTime>averageAccessTime)
    {
        minAverageAccessTime =averageAccessTime;
        listWithMinimumAverageAccessTime = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't print all its permutations here.but I want to say that instead of printing the permutation with least average access time! it will always print that last permutation which is incorrect and I need help to correct it.

Comment: Your question is vague.  What you have presented is the symptom of a bug with no real question.

Comment: I couldn't find better topic ! sorry

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your else if say if `minAverageAccessTime<averageAccessTime` rather than greater than.

Comment: sorry I couldn't get what you mean? would you explain more?